# ReactJS: Appending data to a-z alphabetic list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm converting a .NET project to ReactJS, and are now facing a problem that I can't seem to find the solution for.

I have a list of data from Firebase, which I want to divide into an a-z alphabetic list.

The data from Firebase is a simple array of strings:

- Banana
- Apple
- Lemon
- Pear

Here's my code from React:

```js
renderList: function() {
  var children = [];
  for(var key in this.props.forums) {
    children.push(
      <div className="forum" key={key}>
      <Link to={"/forum/" + this.props.forums[key].id}>
      {this.props.forums[key].title}
      </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
  return children;
}
```

I then have an alphabetic list from a-z:

- A
- B
- C
- etc.

The a-z list I generate using a small js script:

```js
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var alphabetList = document.getElementById("alphabetList");

for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  var nextChar = letters.charAt(i);
  var letter = "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'><div id='" + nextChar + "'><h2>" + nextChar + "</h2></div></div>";
  alphabetList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', letter);
}
```

I don't know if this would be the right way of doing this also..?

Anyway, I would like to append my list of fruits to the a-z list, like so:

- A

  - Apple
- B

  - Banana
- L

  - Lemon
- P

  - Pear

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you have something like this :

```
var forums = [{title:"Apple", id:1}, {title:"Banana", id:2}, {title:"Lemon", id:3}, {title:"Pear", id:4}]
```

According to me the easiest solution would be to use Underscore (or to copy their function http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) and then do it that way :

```
var orderForums = _.groupBy(forums, function(forum) {
    return forum.title.charAt(0)
})
```

Then pass it to your component as props and have a component with a render like this :

```
renderList: function() {
    var letters = []
    for (letter in this.props.forums) {
        var forums = this.props.forums[letter].map(function(forum) {
            return <div className="forum" key={forum.id}>
                    <Link to={"/forum/" + forum.id}>
                        {forum.title}
                    </Link>
                </div>
        letters.push(<li key={letter}>{letter}<ul>{forums}></ul></li>)
    }
    return letters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very basic non-React version to show the approach:

```js
var fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Lemon', 'Lychee', 'Pear'],
  result = '',
  index = '';
fruits.sort();
fruits.map(function(fruit) {
  if (fruit.charAt(0) != index) {
    if (index.length) result += '</ul>';
    index = fruit.charAt(0);
    result += '<li>'+index+'<ul>';
  }
  result += '<li>'+fruit+'</li>';
})
result += '</ul>';
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

So in this scenario I loop over the fruits instead of the alphabet, since you only want to show index/tabs for fruits that are present. This is unlike for example in a physical address book, where the indexes are pre-printed, so cover the full range even when you have no contact whose name starts with that letter.